# ¿Por qué estoy obteniendo solo un elemento en mi array en Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un `servicio` `order-detail.service.ts` que devuelve el detalle de la orden de compra del usuario. Cuando me **subscribo** a la respuesta del servicio, guardo los datos en un `array` **orderDetailArray**.
seguido de esto, con un `foreach` recorro el `array` y le envio como parametro el **"id_product"**
a la funcion `getBookById(id_product)`.
La funcion `getBookById(id_product)`emplea el `servicio` `book.service.ts` y guarda en el `array` **bookArray** el producto/libro correspondiente.
En conclusión, si **orderDetailArray** contiene 3 elementos, La funcion `getBookById()` debería rellenar el **bookArray** con 3 productos/libros.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que aunque **orderDetailArray** tenga varios elementos, en el **bookArray** siempre obtengo un solo producto/libro. Me pregunto si este problema podría ser por tener anidamiento de `subscribe`.

aca `component.ts`

```js
orderDetailArray: OrderDetail[] = [];
bookArray: Book[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const idOrder = params.idOrder;
      // obtengo el detalle de la orden de compra
      this.orderDetailService.getOrderDetail(idOrder).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.orderDetailArray = res;
          // recorro el array
          this.orderDetailArray.forEach(element => {
            const idBook = element.id_product.toString();
            // Obtengo el libro
            this.getBookById(idBook);
          })        
        },
        err => console.error('error al obtener el order_detail ' + err)
      );

    });
  }

  getBookById(idBook: string){
      this.bookService.getBookById(idBook).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.bookArray = res;
        },
        err => console.error('error al intentar obtener el libro por id ' + err)
      );
  }
```

aca `order-detail.service.ts`

```js
getOrderDetail(idOrder: number){
  return this.http.get<OrderDetail[]>('http://localhost:4000/getOrderDetail/' + idOrder);
}
```

`book.service.ts`

```js
getBookById(id: string){
  return this.http.get<Book[]>(`${this.URL_API}/${id}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los observables son operaciones asíncronas y, dentro de tu función estas reescribiendo el arreglo cada vez. Al no tener un orden de resolución solo el último resultado se agregara al arreglo.

```
getBookById(idBook: string){
      this.bookService.getBookById(idBook).subscribe(
        res => {
          //Estas sobreescribiendo el array. Agrega un push con los tres puntos. 
          this.bookArray.push(...res)
        },
        err => console.error('error al intentar obtener el libro por id ' + err)
      );
  }
```

Comment: gracias olvide el push!!!, pero estoy teniendo este error ahora: Argument of type 'Book[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Book'.
  Type 'Book[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Book': name, year, id_author, id_category, and 7 more

Comment: Edite la pregunta. Agrega `...` para que cada elemento se agregue, no como un arreglo.

Comment: Ahora si funciona perfecto! muchas gracias.